# Using find output with rsync --files-from option

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to get the --file-from option of rsync working, but can't. 
Essentially, I want to scan with find first and then make a file from its output. Then I want rsync to read that file with file-from and only send what's specified in the file. 
But it doesn't do that, it sends everything. 
Example: 
rsync -r -i --files-from=<(find thisdir/ -not -path '*parent4*' -not -path "*parent5*") ./ root@10.125.126.115:/root/

'thisdir' is in the current working directory.
Rsync should send nothing nested under the 'parent4' and 'parent5' subdirectories. 
But:

```
cd+++++++++ thisdir/parent5/
<f+++++++++ thisdir/parent5/thisfile
cd+++++++++ thisdir/parent5/subdira/
cd+++++++++ thisdir/parent5/subdirb/
cd+++++++++ thisdir/parent5/subdirc/
cd+++++++++ thisdir/parent5/subdird/
```

It does.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `-r` as this will recurse for each found item.

Also, `find thisdir/ -not -path parent4` will not work as the path glob pattern must be complete, so you would need for example `-not -path '*/parent4/*'`. This matches (and exludes) everything under the directory, but you also need `-not -path '*/parent4'` to exclude just the directory.

Typically, to do this sort of exclusion one can use `-prune` to stop find descending further. Eg:

```
find thisdir/ '(' -path '*'/parent4 -o -path '*'/parent5 \) -prune -o -print
```